# How does tick off come to mean reprimand, scold.etc., where does it comes from?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I read "his father ticked him off in his birthday."

Comment: I've always understood "tick", in this sense, to mean "irritate".  And I assumed it related to the insect.  "I'm ticked off" would be likely to be said by someone who was moderately angry, back in the 70s.

Comment: @HotLicks According to dictionaries, _ticked off_ meaning _annoyed_ is US English. The OP is referring to the British sense - _told off, reprimanded_.

Comment: @KateBunting - How do you know?

Comment: @HotLicks From the title, of course!

Comment: @KateBunting - So is using "means" like that a Britishism?

Comment: @HotLicks I said nothing of the kind. I understand the OP to mean "How does _tick off_ come to mean _reprimand_?"

Comment: @KateBunting Not sure why Hot Licks has gone hot-under-the-collar - but I suspect it has to do with the fact that the questioner mis-conjugated "means". It should have been "mean".

Comment: @KateBunting -- The "quote" does not necessarily imply reprimand/scold, but simply "anger" (as a verb).

Comment: @HotLicks Without context, it could imply either, and the OP evidently understands it in the British sense.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently from UK military slag from the early 1900s.

> The 'chastised' meaning is of UK military origin and dates from the early 20th century and is now rather outmoded. It is usually applied to a child or subordinate. the earliest known citation of it in print is in a 1915 letter which was later published in Wilfred Owen's Collected Letters:
>
> - *"He has been 'ticked-off' four or five times for it; but is not yet shot at dawn."*

([The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/382100.html))

Probably from the earlier sense of “making a mark beside an item on a list”

> perhaps via World War I military bureaucratic sense of being marked off from a list as "dismissed" or "ineligible."

([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tick))

Comment: When all the boxes are tick, it is *to have the right qualities to be a good choice or solution*. Source: Cambridge Dictionary. English is interesting

Comment: I've always taken it as a rather more mild expression of "told off". "Ticked off" never sounds quite as bad to me as "told off".